# Conditional Statement Outside of the Loop in wordpress [in header]

Tags: wordpress, loops, conditional-statements, field

Have an image in my header.php file that i want to have change if a custom field is present. Needs to be conditional in case the field is empty, or if you are on the index.php page.

Tried the outside the loop code, and ive tried conditional statements for within the loop, not sure how to combine

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
if (is_page()) {
  $pageid = get_query_var('page_id');
  if (get_post_meta($pageid, '_wp_page_template', true) != 'index.php' &&
     ($custom_field = get_post_meta($pageid, 'custom field name', TRUE)) {
    //code to change image
  }
}
```

Comment: posts as well? Thank you btw!

Comment: you're welcome. so does it work? if it has to happen for posts, then need to know if every post will have the same custom field